# Simple software program for converting H264 video in to flashvideo flv for website?

Tags: video, file-formats, video-editor, premiere, full-hd

my question is:

**Which simple, lightweight, straightforward, easy to use software for Win7 can do the following:**

A) import/convert on the fly MP4 (H264) movie into FLV (Flashvideo) and apply following:

B) Downscale FullHD footage from 1920x1080 into exactly half 960x540 pixels.

C) Simple color toning or sharpess effects will be great

The MP4 movies are recorded in Full HD and come from an Android 4.0 device that captures footages in great detail. I tried Premiere but thats too heavy/expensive/too much)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg can do this. By "FLV (Flashvideo)" I assume you mean "FLV1 / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263". Not sure why anyone would choose this these days over H.264.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v flv1 -q:v 2 -filter:v scale=iw/2:-1,hqdn3d output.flv
```

What the options mean:

- `-c:v flv1` Choose the encoder named `flv1`
- `-q:v 3` Quality level. Range is 1-31 (for MPEG-1/2/4, excluding H.264) and a higher value is a lower quality.
- `-filter:v scale=iw/2:-1,hqdn3d` Filters that will:

  - Scale your video to half the size of the input then
  - Apply the de-noise filter `hqdn3d`

Windows users can download recent FFmpeg from [Zeranoe FFmpeg Builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Answer (score 3):

Use Mpeg Streamclip, its an industry used conversion software that is reliable and fast, and free

Answer (score 2):

Either [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) or [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)+[Avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page)(+[Avanti](http://avanti.arrozcru.com/)) will do the job. The former should be faster to get going.